# Use MSBuild to Update a Program

Tags: c#, exe

We use a MSBuild do create a Setup.exe. This Setup.exe will be uploaded on a Server and the programm use this file to reinstall the new Version of the program. My task is to speed up this process.

I would like to write a MSBuild which compiles the exe. So the customer don't need to download the whole 40mb but rather it updates his program.

Is that possible with MSBuild or is there another (better) solution.

Comment: ClickOnce https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created patches.

I just want to give a short answer. It will probably be superficial.
So, everything is generated with a build.msbuild file.
Create folders with all the versions of the program (1.0.0.0, 1.0.1.0,…). Each folders also contains a .wixpdb file. This file is needed to generate the patches. 
I created a msbuild-Task in C# to automate the patch generation. It looks like that:

```
…
foreach directory
…
if (!startTool("candle","\""+wurzel + "\\Setup\\MSI\\Patch.wxs\" -o \""+wurzel+"\\Setup\\MSI\\Patch.wixobj\""))
return false;
if (!startTool("light","\"" + wurzel + "\\Setup\\MSI\\Patch.wixobj\" -o \"" + wurzel + "\\Setup\\MSI\\Patch.wixmsp\""))
return false;
if (!startTool("torch", " -p -xi \"" + older.wixpdb + "\"  \"" + newer.wixpdb + "\" -out \"" + wurzel + "\\Setup\\MSI\\Patch.wixmst\""))
return false;
if (!startTool("cmd", "/c cd /d \""+wurzel+"\\Setup\\MSI\" && pyro Patch.wixmsp -t MyPatch Patch.wixmst -out \"" + wurzel + "..\\Release\\Patches\\Patch_" + kvp.Value + "-" + versionNrS + ".msp\""))
return false;
…
```

The program automatically downloads the right patch and installs it with this command:

```
"msiexec /qb /p " + fd.Directory.FullName + "\\"+currentFtp.FileName + "  REINSTALL=ALL REINSTALLMODE=a”
```